# Prompt user to send app crash info to Airbrake

Tags: android, airbrake

I am using [airbrake](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-android) to catch crash reports

As soon as the app crashes I can see the report on the dashboard, but there is no alert in my app to ask the user to "Send Error Report". How can I enable airbrake alerts to ask the user to send the report for the crash. Could not find anything related to this on airbrake documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the `AirbrakeNotifier` code you linked to reveals that it [automatically sends crashes](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-android/blob/8a844c7/src/com/loopj/android/airbrake/AirbrakeNotifier.java#L178-L179) as soon as possible.

You would have to modify this class to ask the user whether to send crashes, e.g. the next time you initialise the Airbrake class.

For example, HockeyApp has an option to do this in its [`CrashManager`](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/blob/2f2f483f68e59abc978abed4580ea1bd310e9305/src/main/java/net/hockeyapp/android/CrashManager.java) class.

Though I prefer to always automatically send crash reports to the server; there's usually no reason to bother users with this request.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send crash report to be send you can make class to handle `UnCaughtException` that will handle all crash exception. You can write code like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.util.Log;

public class UnCaughtException implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private Context context;
    private static Context context1;

    public UnCaughtException(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        context1 = ctx;
    }

    private StatFs getStatFs() {
        File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        return new StatFs(path.getPath());
    }

    private long getAvailableInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return availableBlocks * blockSize;
    }

    private long getTotalInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
        return totalBlocks * blockSize;
    }

    private void addInformation(StringBuilder message) {
        message.append("Locale: ").append(Locale.getDefault()).append('\n');
        try {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo pi;
            pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            message.append("Version: ").append(pi.versionName).append('\n');
            message.append("Package: ").append(pi.packageName).append('\n');

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CustomExceptionHandler", "Error", e);
            message.append("Could not get Version information for ").append(
                    context.getPackageName());
        }
        message.append("Phone Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL)
                .append('\n');
        message.append("Android Version: ")
                .append(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append('\n');
        message.append("Board: ").append(android.os.Build.BOARD).append('\n');
        message.append("Brand: ").append(android.os.Build.BRAND).append('\n');
        message.append("Device: ").append(android.os.Build.DEVICE).append('\n');
        message.append("Host: ").append(android.os.Build.HOST).append('\n');
        message.append("ID: ").append(android.os.Build.ID).append('\n');
        message.append("Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append('\n');
        message.append("Product: ").append(android.os.Build.PRODUCT)
                .append('\n');
        message.append("Type: ").append(android.os.Build.TYPE).append('\n');
        StatFs stat = getStatFs();
        message.append("Total Internal memory: ")
                .append(getTotalInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
        message.append("Available Internal memory: ")
                .append(getAvailableInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        try {
            StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder();
            Date curDate = new Date();
            report.append("Error Report collected on : ")
                    .append(curDate.toString()).append('\n').append('\n');
            report.append("Informations :").append('\n');
            addInformation(report);
            report.append('\n').append('\n');
            report.append("Stack:\n");
            final Writer result = new StringWriter();
            final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            report.append(result.toString());
            printWriter.close();
            report.append('\n');
            report.append("**** End of current Report ***");
            Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
                    "Error while sendErrorMail" + report);
            sendErrorMail(report);
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
                    "Error while sending error e-mail", ignore);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method for call alert dialog when application crashed!
     */
    public void sendErrorMail(final StringBuilder errorContent) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                builder.setTitle("Sorry...!");
                builder.create();
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Report",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                String subject = "Your App crashed! Fix it!";
                                StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("Yoddle");
                                body.append('\n').append('\n');
                                body.append(errorContent).append('\n')
                                        .append('\n');
                                // sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                                sendIntent
                                        .putExtra(
                                                Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                                new String[] { "your_email@domain.com" });
                                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                        body.toString());
                                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                        subject);
                                sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                                context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });
                builder.setMessage("Oops,Your application has crashed.");
                builder.show();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

And declare this exception class in every `Class` file to get log of each crash. Following code you can use to add in `Activity` or any other class:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(
                YourActivity.this));
```

Comment: Thanks, but for sending the crash report I'm using airbrake SDK. I just need to show alerts to the user to opt if he wants to send the report to airbrake or not..

Comment: I think she has mentioned in the question that she is using `airbrake`!